# Unable to track memory issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, xcode-instruments

I am having problem on memory leak tracking, i did try profiling but the instrument shows **firapb_decode_repeated_user_attribute as**  as responsible object. And while i try to track code it takes me to assembly code which is more painful. Do anybody have similar issue or have some clue to track this issue, It will be a lot for me.

### Leaked Object # Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Frame Malloc 32 Bytes 1 0x600000231ba0 32 Bytes appName firapb_decode_repeated_user_attribute

[image]

### The Assembly code

[image]

Comment: Please stop adding inappropriate tags. Please read the description of the Apple tag.

Comment: i think that tag is related to this issue, it might be sdk related issue too.

Comment: @dip No, read the description of Apple Tag: "DO NOT USE THIS TAG!!! Apple is the company that manufactures Macs and iOS devices. Use tags more relevant to the OS and device/computer you're targeting.". So target iOS. Also, your issue seems to be related to FireBase, or with your implementation of it. Did you check with FireBase (FIRA...Stuff)?

Comment: okey, yes i was suspecting the firebase but FIRA is only the word that trying to connect firebase to this issue, i will tag firebase here now, btw thnks.

Comment: Have you found something on it? I also have a few leaks with `firapb_decode_repeated_user_attribute` and one with `firapb_decode_repeated_setting`... I seems to come with Firebase, that's all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as Larme said it was the **Firebase** leaking the memory.

I am still not knowing the exact cause (line of code) but **disabling firebase app analytics** from ***firebase plist*** solved the problem,

Even you are not using firebase app analytics with setting **IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED = NO** *on GoogleService-Info.plist*. fire base SDK seem executing the app analytic codes by default.

**Solution:-** Adding FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED = NO on GoogleService-Info.plist, wipe out the leak problem.

This is only my perception and observation, this topic may need more information and expiations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the area of your code where the leak occurs, switch to the call tree view. The jump bar is at the top of your first screenshot. Click the Leaks item in the jump bar and choose Call Tree to switch to the call tree view.

When you're in the call tree view, selecting the Invert Call Tree and Hide System Libraries checkboxes will make it easier to find your code in the call tree view. Starting with Xcode 8.3, the checkboxes are in a popover that you open by clicking the Call Tree button at the bottom of the window.

[image]

Earlier Instruments versions have a display settings section with a Call Tree collection of checkboxes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks i will try with inverting call tree.