# how to solve iPhone app memory leak in xcode(instruments)

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

Now i'm developing iPhone app but it seems happen memory leak. I found by Instruments:

[image]

I have question:

-- how to find where is code that happen memory leak about "Malloc xx bytes"?

-- I think I can't improve memory leak in Library. Example for "Foundation", "StoreKit" and so on, right?

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the call tree view to find the areas of your code allocating the leaked memory. For more detailed information, see my answer to the following question:

[Unable to track memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464035/unable-to-track-memory-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Also for clearer representation of memory leaks select Allocation tool, go to File>Recording Options and tick "Discard events for freed memory".

In this way all the spikes that you will see in the chart will be actual unfreed memory